# check if file exists without allocating memory

Tags: java

I need to check if a file exists without allocating memory for it. I just want to check that it exists, I am not interested in getting the content. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes: use a search engine. Next time just try putting your question into google. Surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.io.File.exists()` method allows you to do just that:

```
boolean fileExists = new File("path").exists();
```

Creating a `File` instance does not read its content on the disk.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the file is on a remote server. How would look the code in that case? Can I put the remote host in the path string?

Comment: @JesusParadinas  Unless the remote server is mapped to a local drive, the File API is pretty much not going to help. What protocol are you using to connect to the remote server?

Comment: I have been told that the servers are mapped. I am not sure how to connect do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @JesusParadinas Then I suppose the code should work. Try it.